# Why are there `move` and `li` two different pseudo-instructions?

Tags: mips

Imagine that there's a single `mov` pseudo-instruction.

```
mov $s0, __
```

When its 2nd argument is a register (say, `$s1`), it will be interpreted as

```
add $s0, $zero, $s1
```

When its 2nd argument is an immediate number (say, `1`), it will be interpreted as

```
addi $s0, $zero, 1
```

But the reality is that there are two different instructions.
Is this better than the imagined `mov` instruction mentioned above?

Comment: Feel free to add support for such a pseudo-instruction to your favorite assembler. Intel notoriously overloads the `mov` opcode to do about a dozen different things (move general-purpose register to general-purpose register, move general-purpose register to/from memory, move general-purpose register to/from segment register, move immediate to general-purpose register, move control register to/from general-purpose register, move debug register to/from general-purpose register, plus variations for all the different register sizes.) Some people like massive overloading of an opcode. Others don't.

Comment: @RaymondChen: So the type and implementation of these MIPS pseudo-instructions depend only on the taste of the assembly compiler manufacturer, right?

Comment: Mostly, yes; assemblers for the same processor differ.  However, the hardware vendor will often make suggestions or an initial recommendation.  Such is the case with RISC V, for example, where you can find pseudo instructions in the official specification: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/riscv-spec-20191213.pdf.  Similar may be true for MIPS.  Given that publication, it would be awkward for an assembler to not support those pseudo instructions.